# Canonical Form Of $yu_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$$yu_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$$

If we look at $$\frac{b\pm\sqrt{b^2-ac}}{a}$$

We get $$\frac{\pm\sqrt{-y}}{y}$$

So we have $3$ cases, for the case of $y<0$ can we say that we have

1.$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\Rightarrow P=\frac{2}{3}y^{1.5}+x$$

2.$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\Rightarrow Q=\frac{2}{3}y^{1.5}-x$$

If so, I get $$u(P,Q)=y(u_{PP}-2u_{PQ}+u_{QQ}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}(u_P+u_Q)+y(u_{PP}+2u_{PQ}+U_{QQ})$$

Where the answer is:
$$u(P,Q)=y(u_{PP}-2u_{PQ}+u_{QQ}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}(u_P+u_Q)-y(u_{PP}+2u_{PQ}+U_{QQ})$$

Where did it went wrong?

Comment: The general form is $Au_{xx}+Bu_{xy}+Cu_{yy}+Du_x+Eu_y+Fu=G$. We have that $A=y$ and $C=1$  and the rest are $0$. This gives us $B^2-4AC=0-4y=-4y$. Now form the characteristic equation.

Comment: I don't normally recommend Youtube videos but [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2uWh9y5Zuw0) looks good (only watched two to three minutes).